# Azure Function with CosmosDb Binding Proper Local Setup

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I can't get this to work. I have installed the Azure Storage Simulator locally and have created an Azure Function 2.0 through Visual Studio 2019.

I can run the function without a CosmosDb binding as follows:

`local.settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "EndpointUri": "https://localhost:8081",
    "PrimaryKey": "<KEY_HERE>"
  }
}
```

`Function.cs`

```
public static class Function
{
    [FunctionName("func")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
        ILogger log
    )
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        var endpointUri = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EndpointUri", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process));
        var primaryKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PrimaryKey");

        using (var client = new DocumentClient(endpointUri, primaryKey))
        {
            var queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };
            var documents = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Doc>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("db_id", "col_id"), queryOptions);

            foreach (var document in documents)
            {
              ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs as expected and gets the documents that I have in my local storage emulator.

I would like to switch this to utilize a CosmosDb binding though and can't seem to find the magical incantations needed to get it to work.

I updated the method signature on `Function.cs` to:

```
public static async Task Run(
            [TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
            ILogger log,
            [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "db_id",
                collectionName: "col_id",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM col_id")
            ] IEnumerable<Doc> documents
        )
```

When I run it though, I get the following error:

> [5/17/2019 3:09:29 PM] Executed 'func' (Failed,
>   Id=8326b1c4-3dd5-461d-b8de-d777c5b925d8) [5/17/2019 3:09:29 PM]
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: func.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'documents'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Value cannot be null. [5/17/2019
>   3:09:29 PM] Parameter name: authKeyOrResourceToken.

I've tried a number of other tinkerings all without any success.

The first was to utilize the default full explicit connectionstring:
`"AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;",` as found in the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#connect-to-the-emulator-account-using-the-well-known-account-name-and-key).

Any idea how I can change the above to execute locally against my Azure Storage Emulator successfully?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ConnectionStringSetting` in the `CosmosDB` binding is the setting for the conenction string for a Cosmos DB account, not the Azure storage. See the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#input---configuration) for each attribute.

Step 1: Add a new setting to your `local.settings.json` with a valid Cosmos DB connection string (it could be the Emulator).

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "EndpointUri": "https://localhost:8081",
    "PrimaryKey": "<KEY_HERE>",
    "CosmosDBConnectionString": "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081;AccountKey=<KEY_HERE>;",
  }
}
```

Step 2: Modify your `Function.cs` to use that new setting:

```
public static async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
    ILogger log,
    [CosmosDB(
        databaseName: "db_id",
        collectionName: "col_id",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnectionString",
        SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM col_id")
    ] IEnumerable<Doc> documents
)
```

Optionally, you can always pull in the `DocumentClient` instance from the binding if you want to manually run the query or do other operations:

```
public static async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
    ILogger log,
    [CosmosDB(
        databaseName: "db_id",
        collectionName: "col_id",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnectionString")
    ] DocumentClient documentClient
)
```

> As a side note, whenever you are creating a `DocumentClient` manually, please follow [these guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#documentclient-code-example-c), never create a `DocumentClient` instance within a `using` statement in each execution.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. re:`using`, the docs tell you not to put `HttpClient` in a using. Is the `DocumentClient` just a wrapper around that which is why you shouldn't use a `using` statement for it as well?

Comment: The doc has a particular section for the `DocumentClient` because of Cosmos DB's [performance guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#sdk-usage) tell about using a Singleton pattern. Part of that is because the client uses `HttpClient` internally. It all boils down to https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/